# GAS: Embed published service to personal domain

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to embed a published Google App Script service into a website with a personal domain?

I am aware that there will be a yellow security banner at the top of the service.

This is the only article that I've found so far:
[python proxy to embed a google apps script service in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10510425/1029121)

I've tried the following code examples with no success:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=[key]" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<embed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" src="https://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=[key]"/>
```

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about embedding it in an iframe, but you can use a personal URL and use Google Sites to host that webpage.

Comment: Thanks, mzimmerman. This solution won't work for me. I also see that they are having [problems](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=546&q=custom%20domain&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script services can't be embedded / iframed into a webpage on a non-Google domain. There is an open [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=852) you can follow for enabling this.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. This seems like it would be a pretty common feature request.