# Using UiApp PopupPanel in Sites

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet feeding data into a list page in a Google Site.  I would like for users to be able to manage this data directly from the list page.

Is it possible to use the PopupPanel in the UiApp service (or some other similar method) to achieve this?

Currently the script that populates the list page creates a URL to call another script with the UI code, but it always opens in a new browser window.  I haven't been able to find any examples out there on how to get the UI to open in the parent window (the list page).

This is probably a pretty rudimentary task, but I'd appreciate any guidance on where to go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you insert it as a Google Apps Gadget Script ? If your script is saved in your site it is available in the list of gadgets to insert and the UI shows up in a window right above your list.

You can have a look at [this test example](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/testlistpage) to see if it meets your requirements (valid lastnames = John, Paul, Mike...)  this example causes a redirect but that's because it uses an anchor, it's just an example ;-)

This is not a 'popup' in a litteral sense since the UI is always there but you could make it less visible when not active by showing only an 'activate' button for example that would trigger another UI in the same window when the user needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe via a (google app engine) proxy - also removes the yellow warning.

[python proxy to embed a google apps script service in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510425/python-proxy-to-embed-a-google-apps-script-service-in-an-iframe)